# Отладка с кодом PHP с файле с другим расширением?

Tags: php, phpstorm, отладка, xdebug

Есть файл с раширением `.php.t`. В нем может быть код *PHP*. Все настройки для отладки в `php.ini` прописаны, отладчик в *PHPStorm* настроен и если поставить breakpoint - вполне себе отлаживает файлы с раширением `.php`. Но если у файла будет расширение `.php.t`, то брейкпойнт не срабатывает и всё.  Ассоциация данного расширения с языком *PHP* в шторме прописана.

**Заметка:** файл не дебажится именно если дебажить всё приложение (поставить бряк и потом в браузере открыть страницу). Если нажать ПКМ и выбрать отладку файла как скрипт, то брейкпойнт срабатывает. Но смысла в этом нет, потому что там может быть вызов каких-либо классов методов, которые, конечно при такой опции не видны (автолода нет же)

В какую сторону копать? Что и где нужно приписать, дописать, настроить, чтобы можно было отлаживать файлы с другим расширением?

Система: Ubuntu 18.04

Php: 7.2

Полные сведения о phpstorm:

```
PhpStorm 2018.3
Build #PS-183.4284.150, built on November 21, 2018
Licensed to lb od
Subscription is active until July 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
```

Comment: А зачем вообще делать расширение файла `*.t`? Какой профит?

Comment: @ArchDemon могу дать координаты разработчика системы дать - поговорите, узнаете))) Там какие-то свои конструкции языка ядра еще написаны бывают. Думаю задумка определения файла как `template`. Типа как у смарти `tpl`. Но только тут всё в кучу))

Comment: А он вообще выполняется?

Comment: @Ghost да. если писать `echo 123;` всё выводится. Да и в принципе то, что там написано - исполняется. Только не дебажится

Comment: PhpStorm eap версия? Как ставили?

Comment: @Ghost Завтра посмотрю версию. Вроде стабильная версия. то ли 2016 то ли 2017 то ли 2018. Ставил уже не помню как. Кажется через репо линукса. Самое интересное все остальные виды отладки работают, как я описал выше

Comment: @Ghost добавил полную инфу о шторме в вопрос

Comment: не смог повторить, последняя версия eap расширение .pl